# modal window will only open using the first element, not the second or the third

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

Html for the multiple images (I am trying to use all of the images with one modal) and have to modal display specific information based on the image that is chosen.

```
  <div id = "items">
  <li id="item">
    <a><img src="images/items/Meat Nugget.png" />
  </li>
  <li id="item">
    <a><img src="images/items/Bustling Fungus.png" />
  </li>
```

JavaScript for making taking in the trigger of clicking on the element

```
(function(){
  var $content = $('#share-options').detach();  

  $('#item').on('click', function() {           
    modal.open({content: $content, width:340, height:300});
  });
}());
```

Comment: An ID must be unique to a single element. To group them together use a class instead

Comment: Where is your enclosing ul or ol tag?

Answer (score 1):

This is because ID is unique to a single element, so each page can only have one element with that ID. You can fix this by using class, you can use the same class on multiple elements.

```
<div id = "items">
  <li class="item">
    <a><img src="images/items/Meat Nugget.png" />
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a><img src="images/items/Bustling Fungus.png" />
  </li>
```

When referencing a class you'll need to use the . (class selector) instead of a # (ID selector)

```
$('.item').on('click', function() {           
    modal.open({content: $content, width:340, height:300});
  });
}());
```